# Does changing the order of double integration (both integral limits are constants) alter the final answer?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, constants

I have studied that changing the order of double integration will not change the answer if both the limits of integration are **constants**. But this function is not agreeing with what I have studied:
$$1)\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1{\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dy}\right)dx$$
$$2)\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1{\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dx}\right)dy$$
The answer to the first integral is **0.5** and that of the second integral is **-0.5** respectively.

Can anyone please explain why is this so?

Comment: Have you checked that the integral of the absolute value is finite? Otherwise you wouldn't be in the conditions of the Fubini theorem.

Comment: $(0,0)$ is a problematic point for $\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}$.

Answer (score 7):

In general you cannot switch the order of integration without additional constraints. These are typically given by [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem). In particular the example you've given does not converge absolutely so switching the order changes the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by absolute convergence? Can you explain it?

Comment: @jigarfaria1995 Sure. Absolute convergence in this case means the convergence of the absolute value of the function. This is analogous to absolute convergence of a series which is defined similarly using the sum of the absolute values of the terms. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It has helped me to understand some other integrals too.

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1{\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dx}\right)dy\\
&=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1{\frac{x+y-2y}{(x+y)^3}dx}\right)dy\\
&=\int_0^1\left[\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}-\frac{2y}{(x+y)^3}\right)dx\right]dy\\
&=\int_0^1\left[\frac{-1}{x+y}+\frac{2y}{2(x+y)^2}\right]_{x=0}^1dy\\
&=\int_0^1\left[\frac{-1}{(1+y)^2}\right]dy\\
&=\left[\frac{1}{1+y}\right]_0^1=-\frac12.
\end{align}
Similarly, you can show that
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1{\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dy}\right)dx=\frac12.
\end{align}